# Given a 2D transformation matrix, how to calculate the scalings, skews, rotations and translations?

Tags: apache-flex, math, matrix, geometry, transform

I wrote a program ([like this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=15_Geometry_6.html)) that generate and apply a transformation matrix to an object thanks to user's input on scalings, skews, rotations and translations.

Now I want to do it inversely: given the transformation matrix, how to calculate the these values? The matrix is 2D (a, b, c, d, tx, ty).

I know this is a pure math problem but I was not concentrated enough in high school...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a lot of useful info on [this tutorial](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) which solved the problem for me. Here is the formula for those who cares:

**Translation** (pixel)

```
x := tx

y := ty
```

**Scale** (time)

```
scale_x := sqrt(a^2 + b^2)

scale_y := sqrt(c^2 + d^2)
```

**Skew** (degree)

```
skew_x := 180/pi * atan2(d, c) - 90

skew_y := 180/pi * atan2(b, a)
```

**Rotation** (degree)

This is the tricky part: rotation is not a basic transform function; in fact it is the result of the combination of skew and scale. You can skew an object by its `x` and `y` axis and then scale it to make it look like it has been rotated. The angle of x skew is usually regarded as the rotation angle:

```
rotation := skew_x
```

Sometimes:

```
rotation := skew_y
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a translate/rotate/scale&skew order of operations, the easiest thing to do is to snip them off one at a time.

1. Extract the last column; it is the translation. discard it and the last row.
2. Find the QR decomposition of the resultant 3x3 matrix. The orthogonal component is the rotation; discard it and keep the upper triangular component.
3. The diagonal of the upper triangular component is the scaling. Reverse it by left-multiplying the upper triangular matrix by the scaling's inverse.
4. The result is the skew matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Please wait while I'm translate this into English then into my code and report back.

Comment: I have added an answer to show the formula I figured out, have a look if you're interested. Thanks.